# On selected index change drop down list is not bind

Tags: asp.net

On drop down list selected Index Change i want bind Drop Down List according the condition.
I am doing this and data is showing if i am using break point but On Front End Drop Down List is not Bind. it shows blank.
My code is given below:

```
 SqlParameter[] param6 = new SqlParameter[] 
           { new SqlParameter("@status","drivershow"),
             new SqlParameter("@FromDateWithStartTime",driverdate),
             new SqlParameter("@dayvalue",dayvalue),
           };


        List<clsDropDown> assigneddriver = comnFunctionObj.getDropDownList(clsConstant.SP_GET_CAR_BOOKING_STATUS, param6);
        ddldriver.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < assigneddriver.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!ddldriver.Items.Contains(new ListItem(assigneddriver[i].DisplayFieldText.Trim(), assigneddriver[i].ValueFieldText.Trim())))
            {
                ddldriver.Items.Add(new ListItem(assigneddriver[i].DisplayFieldText.Trim(), assigneddriver[i].ValueFieldText.Trim()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: So if you add a breakpoint at `ddldriver.Items.Add` it will stop there? Is this in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ddldriver`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bind the data after adding items to DropDownlist as:`ddldriver.DataBind();`

```
ddldriver.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < assigneddriver.Count; i++)
        {
          // add items  
        }
// now bind the Data to the Dropdownlist   
ddldriver.DataBind();
```

Check also if `assigneddriver`  list is not null.